# Which sci-fi movie/episode had bleeding rocks on a planet?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, robots, space-exploration

I'm trying to find a long lost movie/series that I saw as a child in the 80s.

The only scenes I can remember is that they are on a planet with no vegetation, only dust and rocks. When using their pickaxes they struck like veins or arteries in the rock that started to bleed (one scene they chip of a larger piece of the rock). Then, if memory serves, in the end they started to communicate with the planet in some way.

The other scene is more vague so can't be sure it's accurate. One of the male crew members (only one?) is injured and stranded on a planet and the crew can't help him (reason unknown to me) so they use a robot to pick him up or a remote controlled vehicle.

The spaceships, if I recall it correctly, looks similar to those of "V", "Space 1999" and the science car in "Ark II".

Comment: Ah, this is so frustrating. I think I can actually remember the scene you speak of, but I just cannot remember what film or show it was on. I think it may have been Star Trek

Answer (score 11):

I believe this is from the show [Space Academy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Academy), specifically Episode 6. "The Rocks of Janus".  A brief synopsis is below. But, the key is what you mentioned. In the show, the Blue team injures Trgo when they take rock samples causing him (it?) to bleed.  The other details as to appearance of the ship and the rescue mission for the crew member using  a robot also match. In fact according to the site, the spaceship's bow was actually a re-used prop from the earlier series Ark II.

> "A pair of comets code-named Janus are on a collision course for the
>   Academy, but when the Blue Team investigates, they discover that the
>   closest comet is actually a sentient being named Irgo. The comet is
>   dying, and came to warn sentient beings about the other comet, a
>   criminal named Targ. Can the Blue Team revive Irgo and defeat Targ?"

Comment: Fantastic!! That's the one! You made my day a better one, thank you. Glad I wasn't too far off with the details.